# Is it better to use a separate JavaScript object for data to be shared among many other JS objects?

Tags: javascript

I am building a Project Management app in PHP and JavaScript.  This question is more around the JavaScript side of it and more of an architecture question.

So I have multiple JavaScript object/class type files which are basically like "modules"...

- TaskModal.js
- ProjectForums.js
- TaskList.js

Just to name a few of the JavaScript files which handle sections of the app.

There are lots more too.  But something they all have in common is that they all need shared access to certain bits of Data.

For example **User List**.  Most of my JavaScript files need access to the User List of all users from the Database.

SO to avoid all my JS files querying the Database to build a separate Userlist, I instead plan to inject a Global JS var as a JSON object with PHP which will hold the Userlist and allow all JS files access to 1 userlist!

To go a step further, I built a JS function into 1 of my first JS files which will check for the existence of the Global Userlist created from the PHP, if it is not found though it will then make an AJAX request and get the list itself!

If it has to fetch the list with AJAX, it will then set it as a Global userList var for the other JS files to hopefully avoid making there own AJAX requests as well.

So the Userlist will be cached for all to access with redundant fallback to make sure it gets loaded!

In my `TaskModal.js` file which is the first file I have added this AJAX fallback for checking for the Userlist in the Global scope and then if it is found in Global, it will cache it to a local var.  If not then it makes the AJAX request.

With this theory and design I would need to basically replicate the same user functions in all my JS files and I am thinking that perhaps that is not he best way...

Should I instead have a separate User object which handles all the above functionality and the only functions for users on the separate JS files will simply be to access this User object?

Below is a simple example of what the TaskModal.js Object might look like with it's own User functionality.  Should all this be moved to a separate User object?  And if it is, would that make it easiar to access the User data from all my JS files?

```
(function (window, document, $, undefined) {
    "use strict";

    //we cache a few useful values, like jQuery wrapped window and document
    var $window = $(window),
      $document = $(document),

    projectTaskModal = {

      // Cache Properties
      cache: {

        isUserObjLoaded: false,
        userList: '',
        isAjaxRequestPending: false,
        getUserListUrlEndpoint: '/post',
        user: {},
        deferred: '',
      },


      /**
       * Initialize projectTaskModal Object and fire off some other init functions
       * @return {[type]} [description]
       */
      init: function() {
        projectTaskModal.users.initUserList();
        projectTaskModal.users.getUserList();
        projectTaskModal.cache.user = projectTaskModal.users.getUserById('1gdfgdfkn123423423');

        console.log('cached User object:', projectTaskModal.cache.user);
      },



      // Get Userlist and other user related functions
      users: {

        initUserList: function() {

          // check for local Flag indicating that Userlist has been loaded.
          // a userlist loaded into DOM as Global var from PHP
          if(projectTaskModal.cache.isUserObjLoaded){

            // Local copy of userlist has already been loaded so we will not search for
            // it in the Global DOM + Not make a server AJAX request to load it
            //
            // Just return our local cached copy of Userlist
            return projectTaskModal.cache.userList;

          }else{

            // this.cache.isUserObjLoaded is FALSE so we must search Global DOM for userlist
            // generated from PHP.

            if (!window.hasOwnProperty('globalUserList')) {

alert('Global userlist is not loaded so load it ourself using AJAX request');
              // Global userlist is not loaded so load it ourself using
              // AJAX request and Promise.
              var loadUserListAjax = projectTaskModal.users.ajaxLoadUserListData()
              .done(function(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    alert('AJAX request success');

                      // Parse JSON response var
                      var userListJson = response;

                      // next set FLAG that userList is loaded
                      projectTaskModal.cache.isUserObjLoaded = true;

                       // After loading userlist from server, cache it locally and to global var for other
                      // JS scripts to use and prevent them from also making AJAX requests!

                      projectTaskModal.cache.userList = userListJson;

                      window.globalUserList = userListJson.user_list;

                      projectTaskModal.cache.isAjaxRequestPending = false;

                      projectTaskModal.users.getUserList();


              }).fail(function(response) {
                  // AJAX request failed
                  console.log('response', response);
                  alert('AJAX request failed');
              }).always(function(response) {
                  projectTaskModal.cache.isAjaxRequestPending = false;

                  // Hide Loader/Spinner
                  setTimeout($.unblockUI, 1000);
              });



            }else{

              alert('Global userlist is loaded so cache it locally and do not make AJAX request!');
              // cache the Global userlist var to local property
              projectTaskModal.cache.userList = window.globalUserList;

              // next set FLAG that userList is loaded
              projectTaskModal.cache.isUserObjLoaded = true;

              projectTaskModal.users.getUserList();

            }
          }
        },


        ajaxLoadUserListData: function() {
            projectTaskModal.cache.isAjaxRequestPending = true;
            return $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              async: true,
              contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
              dataType: 'json',
              url: '/restful/fortune',
              data: {
                action: 'load-userlist'
              },
            });
        },



        getUserList: function() {
            if(projectTaskModal.cache.isUserObjLoaded){

                console.log('userList',projectTaskModal.cache.userList);
            }else{
                console.log('userlist Obj not loaded =(');
            }
        },


        getCurrentUser: function(user_id) {
            if(projectTaskModal.cache.isUserObjLoaded){
                myUserData[1].username
                console.log('userList',projectTaskModal.cache.userList);
            }else{
                console.log('userlist Obj not loaded =(');
            }
        },


        getUserById: function(user_id) {
          var userList = projectTaskModal.cache.userList;
          for (var i = 0; i < userList.length; i++) {
            if (userList[i].id === user_id) {
               user = {
                  id: userList[i].id,
                  username: userList[i].username,
                  role: userList[i].role,
                  gravatar: userList[i].gravatar,
               }
              return user;
            }
          }
          throw "Couldn't find object with user_id: " + user_id;
        },

      },
    };


    // Run Init on DOM Ready
    $(function() {
        projectTaskModal.init();

    });

}(this, document, jQuery));
```

---

**Wasted Memory?**

With the current method where I do not have a separate User object. I am basically storing a Userlist in:

- A Global variable
- A local var for each of the 3 separate JS object files

This seems like it could be wasting a lot of memory?  Would storing the userlist and data in its own dedicated User object cut the 4x Userlist down to 1?

---

**Quick Read - Goal Outline**

I have 3 or more JavaScript files/objects in my Project Management App which all need access to shared data such as `Userlist`, `Debug/Mocking`, `Milestones List`, `Tags List`, and more!

Instead of having each of these object files load the data from server with AJAX requests separately loading the same content over and over on same page load, I want to load once and cache and share among all the JS objects/files.

As I am new to JS, I am not certain of the best route to accomplish this yet without using 3rd party libraries! (jQuery is ok)

For simplicity assume there are 3 JS objects/files and the Userlist is the only thing to share among them.

On page load I 1st attempt to load the Userlist as a JSON object into DOM as a Global variable using PHP.

I want to have a fallback for if it is not found though so that the JS can make an AJAX request to load the userlist if it needs to.  IT would load the userlist, cache it locally for the object doing the work and then also cache it as a Global variable just as the PHP was supposed to do!  After it is cached Globally then the next JS file to check for the Global Userlist should find it and cache it locally to itself without needing to do any server requests.

My concern here is that I would need to replicate this loading/caching mechanism across all 3 JS objects/files!

Also I think it might result in taking a lot of memory that is could avoid?

So my main question is does the way I described above, seem lik a bad method?  Are the issues I mentioned real issues?  And then if that is all true, what is the alternative better routes?

I am thinking that perhaps instead of having to replicate all this User code into the 3 objects/JS files, that it could maybe instead be it;s own `User{}` object.

If there is a User object to handle loading the Userlist and checking it;s existence and all that stuff, then how would I best access this User object data inside my other 3 JS object/files?

I hope this makes soem sense, it was difficult for me to explain it.

Comment: The `UserList`, `TagsList`, etc. are essentially collections - objects that "inherit" from some Collections generic object that contains functionality for interfacing with the server.  Each collection is filled once the page is loaded and as application runs some RESTful syncing could take place between a server and client when changes are made to the collection on either server or client.  For real-time and especially multi-user communication like this, socket.io seems ideal.  However, PHP may not be optimally suited for something like this.  For ideas, take a look at backbone.js source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can separate your concerns a bit further by making a set group of js files handle a data layer. We could name these `services`. Also another set of `modules` which would handle the flow of the app (or UI plugins eg. an image gallery) and use the data managed by the data layer. This sounds all pretty and stuff, lets jump into code with a pattern I like to use on certain projects.

In the first js file I load I define a global namespace for my project

```
// main.js
(function(){
    window.MyCoolProject = {
        services: {},
        modules: {},
        helpers: {},
        laserGuns: {},
        etc: {}
    };
})();
```

This way we expose our public methods in an organized manner to the rest of our code and avoid collisions with other js libraries. Then we load our data layer.

```
// services/user.js
// this file has all the functions required to load user data, these will be a bunch of ajax calls

(function(){

    // we can use this to cache data, even though we can cache via jquery. more on this later
    var cached = {};

    MyCoolProject.services.UserService = {
        getUsers: function(callback){
            // if the cache object has a 'users' property, we have already loaded this data so we returned the cached version of this. Note that we don't return data, we pass it through a callback as a asynch call
            if (cache.users){
                 callback(cache.users);
                 return;
            }
            // if there is no cached data, we make the ajax call
            $.ajax({
                 url: 'path/to/api.json'
                 method: 'GET',
                 // jquery also provides a cache for ajax calls, you can experiment with both to see which better suits your needs
                 cache: true,
                 success: function(data){
                     // once loaded we can manually cache the data
                     cache.users = data;
                     callback(cache.users);
                 }
            });
        },
        getUser: function(id, callback){ ... },
        etc: function(callback){ ... }
    };
})();
```

This way when you call

```
MyCoolProject.services.UserService.getUsers(function(users){
    console.log(users); // will be the same list of users, despite how many times you call it. You will get the same cached version
});
```

Moving along into modules. These I believe can be the same code you already have but changing the way data is loaded to call functions in the service layer like above. You can call the same function in different files and there will be no duplicate data. However there is a js gotcha!

In js, objects (and arrays) are stored as references to each other. This means that doing stuff like:

```
var a = {},
    b = a,
    c = b;
```

Means that `a` is the same as `c` and any change to `a` will be reflected in `c`. Internally it is the same chunk of memory but I'm sure there are people more qualified than me to explain this. Basically no need to worry about memory consumption if you pull the same data object into different other places. What you have to take care is that one module does not alter that data because it will change for all other modules. If in some case you need to alter the data object, you will have to clone it before (see $.extend() in jquery).

According to all this mumbo jumbo a module would look something like this

```
// modules/userImageGallery.js
// a strange image gallery that shows a mugshot of each user
(function(){
    // we autoexecute the module and push its public methods into its namespace
    MyCoolProject.modules.UserImageGallery = (function(){

        var users = [];

        MyCoolProject.services.UserService.getUsers(function(data){
            users = data;
        });

        function next(){ currentUserIndex++; }
        function prev(){ currentUserIndex--; }

        ... etc ...

        // we expose the desired methods
        return{
            next: next,
            prev: prev
        };
    })();
})();

// now we, or any other module, can control the image gallery by calling
MyCoolProject.modules.UserImageGallery.next();
```

Note that there are several patterns to use in javascript. There are closures, prototypes, singletons (object with functions), etc. Whats important is that the public functions are pushed into the corresponding global namespace.

I hope by now you see how this benefits your code organization, you can keep growing and adding modules and services and keep everything organized, yet accesible to others. A side benefit is that you have access to these methods via the console so you can run tests much more easily.

**Looking to the future**

Given that you mention that you are new at javascript, I'd recommend going the frameworkless approach like you are doing. This way you will learn all the tweaks and perks of js. Once you feel comfortable consider looking into angular or ember or any other data binding framework. These offer improved separation of concerns, more control over the flow of your app, improved security and dependency management. Hope you enjoy the ride!

Comment: Great answer.  I've actualyl got many years of playing with JS but just a couple where I am trying to learn the ins and outs and sometimes just hearing the same thing I have read a million times worded differently can make the difference!  I have been playing with a modular approach and I like your demo, very nice.  It seems to be what I had in my mind but I had a big question mark on it and now you have reaffirmed that it is correct so thanks for taking the time to explain in detail!